# Storing Access Token Temporarily in .NET Core API 3.0

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

I'm making requests to an external API for data. Basically first I need to request for an access token which expires in 1 hour. I should use this token for all my requests until it expires then I request for another one.

```
{
    "access_token": "36gZ1EHxmaQI2h4GSSD",
    "expires_in":3599
}
```

I therefore designed my app as per diagram below. So I need a way of storing the token in the backend api (thinking of a server side cookie) I'm not sure how to achieve that in .NET core.

[image]

Comment: please search about refresh token it will help you

Comment: You can refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/additional-claims?view=aspnetcore-3.1#save-the-access-token)